# How to increment my integer only every 50 experience instead of every time?

Tags: java, for-loop

I am programming an RPG game; every time the player earns 50 points of experience (50XP,100,150,200, etc.), he should level up by one level.

```java
int level = 1;
int xp = 0;

//getters - setters

Player player = new Player();
player.fight(); //does something...
player.levelUp();

public void levelUp(){

  if(this.getXp()>=50){

    this.setLevel(this.getLevel() + 1);
  }

}
```

This is not working, because it adds 1 to the level every time, but I only want it to add 1 after every 50 XP ( 100, 150, 200, etc.)

How can I do this?

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: Learn the remainder operator, `%` as it may help you do what you want: `if (getXp() % XP_MAX == 0) {...}` (avoid magic numbers too -- XP_MAX could hold a value of 50 or whatever is needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely want to use the remainder operator, `%` to help you perform your action every 50 xp points. Note that `getLevel() % 50` will return 0 for level values that are divisible by 50 such as 50, 100, and 150, and so code like this might work:

```
public void level() {
    // MAX_XP is an int constant == 50
    if (getXp() % MAX_XP == 0) {
        setLevel(getLevel() + 1);
    }
}
```

If xp changes in increments greater than one, then you might want to calculate the level based on int division and change it, if the int division result changes.

Comment: OK. But what if the XP is 51?                                I want level 2 between 50 and 100,                         I want level 3  between 100 and 150, and etc.

Comment: @Daniel: What happens when you try it?? And look up the `%` operator to see how it is used and what it does. You don't want to use this site as a substitute for your own experimentation and searching.

Comment: You're assuming XP is always incremented by 1. Might be safer to `setLevel(getXp() % MAX_XP + 1)`.

Comment: @shmosel: true. Or do int division, and check for change. That's probably the best way. Note that the answer is a comm wiki, so please improve if you see fit.

Comment: That's what I meant.